# In R Shiny conditional panel, why am I unable to render multiple plots in the same main panel?

Tags: r, shiny

Currently by default as drafted in the below MWE, when first invoking the App, and also when clicking the "Base rate" radio button, only "plot1" is rendered. Instead, I would like both "plot1" and "plot2" to be rendered in the main panel (when first invoking the App and when clicking the "Base rate" radio button). Say one beneath the other. I would like a click of the "Spreads" radio button to continue rendering only "plot2", as it currently does.

I have tried modifying, in `ui` section, `conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tab2 == 'Base rate'",plotOutput("plot1")),` by adding `tagList(plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot2"))` but this and other attempts have not worked.

I've had no problems with multiple plots when running this with `fluidPage` instead of `pageWithSidebar`, so I suspect there is some peculiarity with `pageWithSidebar` and/or `conditionalPanel` that I don't yet understand.

I have resisted trying `renderUI` to resolve this, but maybe that's the answer. I've been trying to move away from `renderUI` for code readability/flow reasons.

MWE code:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)

rate1 <- matrix(c(1:20), 20, 1, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Base rate")))
rate2 <- matrix(c(21:40), 20, 1, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Spreads")))

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Model"),
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Rates", value=2,
                 fluidRow(
                   radioButtons(
                     inputId = 'tab2',
                     label = "",
                     choices = c('Base rate','Spreads'), 
                     selected = 'Base rate',
                     inline = TRUE
                   ) 
                 ), 
                 conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tab2 == 'Base rate'",plotOutput("plot1")),
                 conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tab2 == 'Spreads'", plotOutput("plot2")),
            ),  
            id = "tabselected"
          ) 
        ) 
      ) 

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({plot(rate1)})
  output$plot2 <-renderPlot({plot(rate2)})
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now the above MWE fixed to address the 2 comments by Stéphane Laurent (can't use same plot > 1 time, and `pageWithSidebar` replaced with `fluidPage`/`sidebarLayout` since `pageWithSidebar` is deprecated:

```
rm(list = ls())

library(shiny)

rate1 <- matrix(c(1:20), 20, 1, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Base rate")))
rate2 <- matrix(c(21:40), 20, 1, dimnames = list(NULL,c("Spreads")))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Rates", value=2,
                 fluidRow(
                   radioButtons(
                     inputId = 'tab2',
                     label = "",
                     choices = c('Base rate','Spreads'), 
                     selected = 'Base rate',
                     inline = TRUE
                   ) 
                 ), 
                 conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tab2 == 'Base rate'",plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot2")),
                 conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tab2 == 'Spreads'",plotOutput("plot3")),
        ),  
        id = "tabselected"
      ) 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({plot(rate1)})
  output$plot2 <-renderPlot({plot(rate2)})
  output$plot3 <-renderPlot({plot(rate2)})  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You cannot use two times `plotOutput("plot1")` in a Shiny app, because duplicated id are forbidden in HTML.

Comment: And FYI, `pageWithSidebar` is deprecated, see `?pageWithSidebar`.

Comment: Oh thank you, I forgot about not being able to use the same plot > 1 time. Btw I dramatically reduced the code for this MWE post based on your prior comments. I've also greatly simplified that convoluted code that you previously pointed out, I realized I couldn't go further in developing the App with such a mess. Also thanks for the note on pageWithSidebar being deprecated. I repost the code with your solutions by editing the original post.